# file sharing over external and internal networks

Tags: networking, router, file-sharing

Please tell me whether it is possible for someone on the external network to see the network folder shares of an internal LAN network in DHCP (192.168.x.x) through a Comp-A on an external network in DHCP (123.123.x.x)

both networks are on different subnets

but Comp-A has access to both networks and can see all the shared drives of both the internal and external networks

using firewall is not an option because **file sharing is required everywhere.**
care is taken from viruses/trojans...
remote desktop etc is disabled on Comp-A

Please let me know.

Thanks and Regards
pk

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In windows, the external machines would need to be assigned to the internal domain.  The ONLY thing I can think of that would make this work is to map those internal folders as drives on COMP-A then share the drives with the external network.

Answer (score 0):

'using firewalls' is not against 'file sharing', most networks make use of routers with enabled packetfilters (aka 'firewalls') anyway.

so, use something like [teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/) to share files through firewalls. if you are on the same (sub)net you can share files without any 3rd party involved.